# How can I get rid of these persistent Warnings/Errors in Firebug?

Tags: debugging, console, firebug, warnings

Below are examples of Warnings/Errors that appear in the Firebug console ALL THE TIME no matter what page or content I am trying to debug:

```
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.
[Break On This Error]   

...ch(c){return _.t}},stringify:function(f){function g(c){return h.call(this,c,a)}v...

cb=gapi.loaded_0 (line 27)

The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed.
[Break On This Error]   

...js -> resource://jid0-agjxxzys0rt1uudxcyinrjbgttc-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/sandb...

content-proxy.js (line 7)
<System>

Exposing chrome JS objects to content without __exposedProps__ is insecure and deprecated. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPConnect_wrappers for more information.
[Break On This Error]   

...sh.js -> resource://jid0-agjxxzys0rt1uudxcyinrjbgttc-at-jetpack/api-utils/lib/sa...

worker.js (line 130)
<System>
```

Here's a screenshot:  http://snaps.vertigofx.com/009/snap000025_2013-04-16_23.01.06.png

A few weeks ago I did some research in hopes of finding a way to get rid of these persistent messages, but to no avail.  I'd really like to get rid of these because I use Firebug a lot and they become quite distracting.  I see the red and I automatically think there's something wrong with my code, no matter how 'used to it' I think I might be.

Come to think of it, I may have posted about this on SO (or another site) before, but got no helpful answers.  I'm hoping this time around I can find get a solution.

(FYI, I think it would be really nice if Firebug had the capability of ignoring specific things and suppress any errors/warnings/messages about those specific things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to duplicate my answer from the [Firebug discussion group post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebug/hZT9ONZxYwQ/fW9tPSZZKh0J):

Uncheck the [*Console* panel options](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_Panel#Options_Menu) *Show Chrome Errors* and *Show Chrome Messages*. Doing so Firebug doesn't log these kinds of messages to its console anymore.

Also there are many other filters you can set via the options menu.

Sebastian

Comment: OMG THANK YOU!  This has been bothering me for far too long, and to think that the solution was so incredibly simple!  Now, just to make sure... this won't hide any messages that may be related to my work, will it?

Comment: They won't hide messages related to your code as long as you are not programming a Firefox extension. These options are meant for browser internal and add-on messages only.